# Is it worth it to purchase a coursera certificate in Machine Learning for grad school apps?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

Specifically I'm applying to some data science programs. As Machine Learning is a relatively advanced topic at the undergrad level and one that is so relevant in the field, I was wondering if it would be enough of a plus on my application to be worth the money?

Comment: I have nothing concrete to say about this but I'm very skeptical that university faculty would care about a Coursera certificate. Possibly more useful in industry. If the Coursera courses lead to you actually doing some interesting work, then fine, but the pseudo-credential itself will not be impressive.

Answer (score 9):

By and large, no. Buying the certificate is meaningless with regards to graduate admissions. You can list MOOCs that you have taken on your CV but do not expect them to carry any weight whatsoever. Admissions will only pay attention to accredited courses.

Note: I say this both as someone who evaluates applicants and as someone who is a lead educator on a MOOC.

Comment: Personally I think the certificates are a bit of a scam and I am forced to offer them with my MOOC. Perhaps people just like to have them on their walls or something, but one gets the same content, certificate or no, and the certificate only means you paid money. That said, it pays for my TA, so that's good.

Comment: The very fact that the OP says "purchase" indicates that they have little actual _verifiable_ value.

Comment: @Buffy Most universities require tuition, so I don't see your point.

Comment: @BradyGilg Tuition doesn't "purchase" you a degree or a cert.

Comment: @Buffy Neither does it on coursera. You still have to complete the coursework to get the certification.

Comment: @BradyGilg, I question the "verifiability" of the result.

Comment: @Buffy You can question whatever you want, but stating that any certificate that requires payment has little value would invalidate nearly all degrees in all universities in the world.

Comment: The key is verifiability. Anyone could have completed the coursework on the MOOC. Mine actually has no evaluative element at all and if one just clicks through all the videos and activities, they can pay for a certificate. The certificate basically means someone was able to click "Next" a whole bunch of times.